# Two different results of Fourier Transform $xe^{-x}$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have a function $f$ defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} xe^{-x} \textrm{ if } x>0,\\
0,\textrm{otherwise}. 
\end{cases}$$

I wish to know the Fourier transform of $f$, i.e,
$${\cal F}(f(x))=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ixy}dx.$$

I could do this with two different methods using the fact that$${\cal F}(f'(x))=iy{\cal F}(f(x)):$$

1. Note that $f'(x)=e^{-x}-xe^{-x}=e^{-x}-f(x).$ So,$$iy{\cal F}(f(x))={\cal F}(f'(x))={\cal F}(e^{-x})-{\cal F}(f(x))$$ that leads to
   $$
   {\cal F}(f(x))=\frac{{\cal F}(e^{-x})}{1+iy}=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}(1+iy)^2}.
   $$
2. Put $g(x)=-e^{-x}-xe^{-x}$, then $g'(x)=f(x).$ So,$${\cal F}(f(x))={\cal F}(g'(x))=iy{\cal F}(g(x))=-iy{\cal F}(e^{-x})-iy{\cal F}(f(x))$$ that leads to
   $$
   {\cal F}(f(x))=-iy\frac{{\cal F}(e^{-x})}{1+iy}=-iy\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}(1+iy)^2}.
   $$

My question is: why are they different? Isn't the image of $f$ unique?

Comment: These functions are not $C^1$, hence the apparent contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note your function is summable, so the Fourier transform is really defined by the integral, as you write. However your function $f(x)$ is really not differentiable. Indeed you are looking at the Fourier transform of $f(x) = \theta(x) x e^{-x}$ where $\theta$ is Heaviside function.

The integral can be done by integration by part (which is almost what you are doing there). Setting $k= 1+iy$ one has

$$
\hat{f}(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-k x} x dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-kx}}{k} dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{(1+i y)^2}\,.
$$

Note that the border term in the integration by part formula is zero.

Comment: why is my second approach incorrect?

Comment: Actually they are both incorrect. Note that $g'(x) \neq f(x)$, and the same holds for the equation at point 1. Also you cannot take the Fourier transform of $e^{-x}$ as it is not a summable function in $x\in[-\infty,\infty]$. So the statement $\mathcal{F}(e^{-x})=1/(1+i y)$ is also wrong. What you are doing there is really $\mathcal{F}(\theta(x) e^{-x})=1/(1+i y)$. If I can suggest, I would really leave aside such kind of "formal" manipulations unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: Again, to be even more clear, you cannot use your third equation with the function that you give.

Comment: You are welcome. Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

The results you are using are valid for functions defined on the whole real line, not only for the positive numbers.

Comment: so, which is true if we are talking in the set of all positive real numbers?